# Registering Nested Regions- Prism

Tags: c#, prism

Here is my strategy,

I have a `ContentView` inside my module which is acting as a container for it's **nested regions**.
The below code was working for me when it was just a single region, but I decided to divide it up.
I was using **Interfaces** for registering types, would be no matter change them with the real contents, That's no matter here.

I know the piece of code I provided have got some errors,
please help me as I think using these Nested regions could clean the code more and it would structure better.
I'm using Unity.

Inside the ContentView**

// Inside a grid

```
            <DockPanel Grid.Column="0" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="Left" />
            <DockPanel Grid.Column="0" prism:RegionManager.RegionName="Right" />
```

Adding the LeftView will cause an error.

**Running the code will give this error :**
{"An exception occurred while creating a region with name 'Left'. The exception was: System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: 
The IRegionAdapter for the type System.Windows.Controls.DockPanel is not registered in the region adapter mappings. You can register an IRegionAdapter for this control by overriding the ConfigureRegionAdapterMappings method in the bootstrapper.\r\n

---

How should I change the code to do the job ?

Should I threat Nested Regions the same as my container region ?

Is the code ordered Correctly ? (Their precedence)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a ContentControl inside your dock panels, and set the region name on that. Dock panels are not supported as regions out of the box.

Comment: can you elaborate a little more on this?